# How do you punch out toes in ski-touring boots?

Tags: skiing, gear, footwear

I've got a pair of custom moulded [Scarpa Spirit 4](http://www.wildsnow.com/976/scarpa-spirit-4-close-look/) touring boots where the big toes are bit too tight (I've lost the nails after a day or two of touring more than once).  What is the proper technique for punch out the toe liners without damaging the liner or overall functionality of the boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull out the liner and step into the shell - if you can fit a finger between your heel and the back of the shell you might be able to remold the liner or buy an after-market liner.  A professional boot-fitter at your local gear store can do it for you, or you can follow the directions to do it yourself in a low temperature oven.  If you have trouble fitting a finger between your heel and the back of the boot, I'd consider new boots.  They will be uncomfortable no matter what you do.

Comment: Is punching out always done with heat? I've got another pair of Solomon boots where the inner left ankle creates a pressure point by afternoon when I'm skiing all day.  What other techniques are there?